# How to pass a list of objects from JavaScript code in a View to an action method in a controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass the list of objects from JavaScript code in a “View” to an action method in MVC “Controller”.
Here is what I am trying to achieve –

MVC model & controller:

```
 Public Class Student
    {
        Public int Id {get; set;}
        Public string Name {get; set;}
        Public string Address {get; set;}
    }

    Public class StudentController : Controller
     {
        Public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Read the data from database, create a list of “Student”
            return View(“Display”, StudentList);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        Public ActionResult OrderStudentList(List<Student> StudentList)
        {
            // Code to ascend/descend list
        }
     }
```

Display.cshtml

```
    @model IEnumerable<Student>
    // Code that displays student list
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Student Name</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction()
            {
                var studentL = @Model.ToList();
                $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("OrderStudentList ", "Student")",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ StudentList: studentL }),
                success: function (response) {
                response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.");
                }
            });    
    </script>
```

As you can see, I am passing a list of “Student” to a view called “Display”. This view has a button called “Student Name”. When that button is clicked, I want to pass the list of “Student” to the action method, “OrderStudentList” in a “StudentController” which will arrange the list in ascending/descending order. But when I run the code, I never get any value for the list in the method “OrderStudentList”.

Here is what I have tried so far for assigning the data value in above code

```
    data:'@Html.Raw(Model.ToList())'
```

```
    data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ToList()));
```

Converted a list to an array and tried to copy each element of a list individually to an element of JavaScript array as follows

```js
        var arrayJs = [];
        for(var i=0; i<= @Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            arrayJs.push(@Model.ElementAt(i));
        }
```

But it gives the syntax error with the “i does not exist in the current context”. Created a ViewModel with Student list as a property

```
        Class StudentList
        {
            Public List<Student> StudentList {get; set;}
        }
```

Tried passing an instance of a viewModel as a JSON object to action method “OrderStudentList”.

Nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `data` object in string quotes? `data: 'JSON.stringify({ StudentList: studentL })',`

Comment: If I do that, nothing happens after clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you were expecting this line to do:

```
var studentL = @Model.ToList();
```

but anyway, you need to convert your model to JSON straight away, your JavaScript function needs to look something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("OrderStudentList", "Student")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ToList()))',
        success: function (response) {
            response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.");
        }
    });
}
```

and your Action method needs to have the following signature:

```
    [HttpPost]
    Public ActionResult OrderStudentList(List<Student> model)
    {
        // Code to ascend/descend list
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.John M. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Student Name</button>
```

This is jQuery which you have to include to use `$` syntax. it is available in your project directory. You just check and update this below line:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    function myFunction() {
        var studentL =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        $.ajax({
             url: "@Url.Action("OrderStudentList", "Student")",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json",
             data: JSON.stringify({ StudentList: studentL }),
             success: function (response) {response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.")}
        });
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this with list as well as an array. At run time the line var studentArr = @Model.ToArray() becomes this: var studentArr = Student[]; and throws error, "Javascript critical error, syntax error"